# Raspberry Pi - Gateway IP Defaults to 0.0.0.0 at every reboot, how do I prevent this

Tags: linux, connection, ip, raspberry-pi, gateway

Title says it all. It seems at every re-boot (or it may be at random), my gateway IP sets to 0.0.0.0.

I am viewing this in sudo route -n.

When this happens, I correct it with sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I could prevent it?

I am very new to the raspberry pi and programming. Usually I have two red lights on the raspberry pi; when this problem arose it seems one of them turns green. What do these lights mean?

Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because as it's not programming related. Ask at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/